How to exactly compare Eigen matrices with potentially different shapes in one operation?
I need to perform exact comparison on (partially) dynamically sized Eigen matrices. However, the obvious approach of mat1 == mat2 asserts out if the matrices are not of the same shape. That's because the implementation of Eigen::MatrixBase::operator== simply performs a coefficient-wise equality check which is then reduced using .all().
The workaround is obvious:
template<typename A, typename B>
inline bool isEqual(const A& a, const B& b) noexcept {
   return a.rows() == b.rows()
       && a.cols() == b.cols()
       && a == b;
}     

However, it feels ridiculous to have to implement this myself. Does Eigen provide the equivalent of this somewhere?

https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1061
